# MySQL if row is duplicated prefer which matches field value

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, select, group-by

I have the following select query. I want to avoid getting the duplicated "EN" row when "ES" row is present. Like prefer ES over EN.

```
SELECT s.soft_id,s.groupby,s.packageid,s.name,s.area,l.min,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT JSON_ARRAY(s.version,s.detailid,s.filesize,s.updatetime)) versions
FROM software s
INNER JOIN langs l ON s.lang_id=l.lang_id
INNER JOIN devices_type t ON (s.familylock_id=t.familylock_id OR (s.familylock_id=0 AND s.devicelock_id=t.device_type_id))
INNER JOIN devices d ON t.device_type_id=d.device_type_id
INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE s.groupby IN(1,2,3)
AND u.token="abc"
AND d.serialno="123456789" 
AND l.min IN("ES","EN")
GROUP BY s.soft_id,s.groupby,s.packageid,s.name,s.area,l.min ORDER BY s.name ASC
```

This is the example result:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RpyC.png)

You can test your query here: http://185.27.134.10/login.php?2=epiz_26706010wejghelqwdtg3e54gVGtSRk1VMUVRVE5QVkdzeFRWaDNhRWxUUldoSldIZzRaa2g0T0daSWVEaG1TSGhvVjIxc1JGb3lkRk5rV0U1cFZsRTlQUT09wejghelqwdtg3e54gsql102.epizy.comwejghelqwdtg3e54gepiz_26706010_test&db=epiz_26706010_test

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in two steps, count how many duplicate rows you have. And by duplicate, I mean identical on one column but differ in ES vs EN. have the table sorted

select the last among the duplicates

[Get top first record from duplicate records having no unique identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178097/get-top-first-record-from-duplicate-records-having-no-unique-identity)

Comment: is there any chance you cant try to apply your idea to my query? because i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Outer join the table twice, looking for a single specific value with each join, and then coalesce the fields in the order you prefer:

```
SELECT s.soft_id, coalesce(les.min, len.min) As min, ...
FROM software s
LEFT JOIN langs les ON s.lang_id=les.lang_id AND les.min = 'ES'
LEFT JOIN langs len ON s.lang_id=len.lang_id AND len.min = 'EN'
...
WHERE s.groupby IN(1,2,3)
   AND coalesce(les.lang_id, len.lang_id) IS NOT NULL
...
```

Windowing functions can do it more efficiently, but they're *still* not support on lots of MySql servers in the wild. If you're using 8.0 or later, you should look into that option.

Comment: i have tried but i dont know how to apply your solution to my query :( also i can run mysql 8

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions as:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by soft_id order by field(l.min, 'ES', 'EN')) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1;
```